# Is there any reason to overload operators with rvalue reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, optimization, rvalue-reference

There is templated vector class(it's about math, not container). I need to overload common math operations. Is there any sense to overload like this:

```
template <typename T, size_t D>
Vector<T, D> operator+(const Vector<T, D>& left, const Vector<T, D>& right)
{
    std::cout << "operator+(&, &)" << std::endl;
    Vector<T, D> result;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < D; ++i)
        result.data[i] = left.data[i] + right.data[i];

    return result;
}

template <typename T, size_t D>
Vector<T, D>&& operator+(const Vector<T, D>& left, Vector<T, D>&& right)
{
    std::cout << "operator+(&, &&)" << std::endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < D; ++i)
        right.data[i] += left.data[i];

    return std::move(right);
}

template <typename T, size_t D>
Vector<T, D>&& operator+(Vector<T, D>&& left, const Vector<T, D>& right)
{
    std::cout << "operator+(&&, &)" << std::endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < D; ++i)
        left.data[i] += right.data[i];

    return std::move(left);
}
```

This works pretty fine with this test code:

```
auto v1 = math::Vector<int, 10>(1);
auto v2 = math::Vector<int, 10>(7);
auto v3 = v1 + v2;

printVector(v3);

auto v4 = v3 + math::Vector<int, 10>(2);

printVector(v4);

auto v5 = math::Vector<int, 10>(5) + v4;

printVector(v5);

//      ambiguous overload
//      auto v6 = math::Vector<int, 10>(100) + math::Vector<int, 10>(99);
```

and prints this:

```
operator+(&, &)
8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
operator+(&, &&)
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
operator+(&&, &)
15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15,
```

There is problem with two rvalue references, but I think it doesn't matter.

Why I want to do that? Because of performance reason, in theory it would work little bit faster without creating new object, but will it? Maybe compilers optimize simple code with `operator +(const Vector& left, const Vector& right)` and there is no any reason for overload rvalue?

Comment: not really clear what is your question. If you want to know if there is any difference in what the compiler can optimize you can always look at its output, eg. here https://godbolt.org/

Comment: `&&` in template function in not the same as `&&` in a non-template function.  In a template function `&&` is a __forwarding__ reference (and reference collapsing rules apply); `&&` in a non-template function is a rvalue reference and no collapsing is done.  You have forwarding references.

Comment: @Richard: only if the parameters has the form T&&,  in case of `foo<T>`  (as is the case here) it is an actual r-value reference.

Comment: @DrewDormann, yes, I mentioned it

Comment: @devalone: How is math::Vector implemented internally? Does it use dynamic memory allocation? If so why? If not, what is the advantage of a move compared to a copy?

Comment: @MikeMB, no it uses simple array `Type data[Size]` I used std::move for prevent compiler error , it could be changed to `return (Vector<T, D> &&)left`.

Comment: You might be interested by [Expression_templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates).

Comment: @devalone: Consider delegation and take by copy: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/60fe6a311128dd77

Comment: `operator+` should return by value , your code actually just modifies the second operand which could surprise coders, and create dangling references.  The `+=` operator should be used for a design that modifies one of the operands

Comment: @tobi303, I tried to compile my test code with optimization, also i used rand to prevent compile-time execution and get this https://pastebin.com/AamaCQPH It seems to variant with rvalue more optimized

Comment: @M.M, what's problem? rvalue references on temporary data, isn't it?

Comment: @devalone rvalue reference can refer to any object, not just temporaries.  Also, if it is temporary data and the person write `auto&& result = x + temporary();` then the result is a dangling reference since it refers to the temporary that is now dead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your implementation of `Vector`:

- If the class is faster to move than to copy, providing the additional overloads for moves could result in performance improvements.
- Otherwise, it should not be faster to provide the overloads.

In a comment, you mentioned that `Vector` looks like this:

```
template <typename T, size_t D>
class Vector
{
   T data[D];
   // ...
};
```

From your code, I also assume that `T` is a simple arithmetic type (e.g., `float`, `int`) where copying is as fast as moving it. In that case, you cannot implement a move operation for `Vector<float, D>` which will be faster than a copy operation.

To make move operations faster than copying, you could change the representation of your `Vector` class. Instead of storing a C-array, you could store a pointer to the data, which allows a much more efficient move operation if the size `D` is large.

As an analogy, your current `Vector` implementation is like an [`std::array<T, D>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) (which holds internally a c-array and needs to be copied), but you could switch to an [`std::vector<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (which holds pointers to the heap and is easy to move). The larger the value `D` becomes, the more attractive should it be to switch from `std::array` to `std::vector`.

Let us look closer at the differences when providing overloads for move operations.

**Improvement: in-place updates**

The advantage of your overloads is that you can use in-place updates to avoid having to create a copy for the result as you have to do in your `operator+(&,&)` implementation:

```
template <typename T, size_t D>
Vector<T, D> operator+(const Vector<T, D>& left, const Vector<T, D>& right)
{
    std::cout << "operator+(&, &)" << std::endl;
    Vector<T, D> result;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < D; ++i)
        result.data[i] = left.data[i] + right.data[i];

    return result;
}
```

In your overloaded version, you can update in-place:

```
template <typename T, size_t D>
Vector<T, D>&& operator+(const Vector<T, D>& left, Vector<T, D>&& right)
{
    std::cout << "operator+(&, &&)" << std::endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < D; ++i)
        right.data[i] += left.data[i];

    return std::move(right);
}
```

However, moving the result will result in a copy when you use your current implementation of `Vector`, whereas in the non-overloaded version, the compiler could get rid of it using [return-value optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization). If you use a `std::vector` like representation, moving is fast, so the in-place update version should be faster than the original version (`operator+(&,&)`).

**Can a compiler do the in-place update optimization automatically?**

Highly unlikely that a compiler will be able to do it without help.

In the non-overloaded version, the compiler sees two arrays which are constant references. It will most likely be able to perform return-value optimization, but knowing that it can reuse one of the existing objects, requires lots of extra knowledge that the compiler does not have at that point.

**Summary**

Providing overloads for rvalues is reasonable from a pure performance perspective if `Vector` is faster to move than to copy. If moving is not faster, then there is no gain in providing the overloads.

Comment: Move of array can't be slower than copy, so it shouldn't make program slower. Reason why I wanted to use overload with rvalue is to prevent of creating additional object in function, but as you mentioned, there is return value optimization, but when I tried to compile in gcc with -O4, optimization wan't maken.

Answer (score 2):

If your vector is cheaper to move than to copy (usually the case when internally it stores a pointer to data which can be cheaply copied) than having overloads for rvlaue references would help performance. You can look at `std::string` and how it has overloads for all kind of possible references in it's two arguments here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B

**EDIT**

Since OP clarifies that internal data representation is a c-style array, there is no benefit of providing multiple overloads. C-style arrays can not be moved cheaply - they are copied instead - so those multiple overloads serve no purpose.

Comment: My vector is just simple array defined like this `T data[D];` and it will be used only with simple types like int, double, etc and I think size of vector won't be bigger than 4.

Comment: Reason why I wanted to use rvalue overload is to prevent creating of additional object.